# What does the candy do?

Tags: miitomo

In the Miitomo Drop game, if you don't get one of the special items, you get 3 pieces of candy.

So far I haven't found anything that I can do with this candy - what use does it have in-game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I have found one use: to get answers to specific questions from your friends.

Eventually you'll have a lot of friends and a lot of answers. Unless you just want to sit around as read them all in the order your Mii presents, you'll have some unheard ones waiting. If you want to hear a specific one, or bribe them to tell you more answers, it costs 2 candy to bribe them. Both actions are options when visiting a friend.

That's all I've found so far.

Comment: Also, if you hit an item you already have in the drop games, you can get x5 candy as an alternate.

Comment: thats a way to get candy, not a way to use it.

Comment: You'll notice that the actual answer tells you how to use it. The comment was just additional information for the sake of convenience and clarity since the information related to the initial post. I'm well aware that's how you get candy.